# How format a partition marked as 'system' in windows 10?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, formatting

How format a partition marked as 'system' in windows 10? This is snapshot of disk management:
[image]

I can't format or remove drive D. My current windows is in Drive C. I want format drive D totally and add 100GB of it to drive C. How can I do this?

Error : windows cannot format the system partition on this disk.

Comment: I guess, because C: is a logical drive, some of your system booting dependencies are on D:, so you cannot boot your system on C: without D:

Comment: @bfrguci. Thank your for your comment. What is your recommendation for this problem?

Comment: Your case is actually pretty complex. Even if you have D: removed, you may still have a hard time merging those space into C:, because D is before C:, which makes it impossible without moving the starting point of C:. However moving the starting point of a system partition may cause boot failures.

Comment: I see a System reserved partition, but D: is activated. Could you please try activating the first small partition, and see if it boots into this Windows? If yes, you can post another figure for diskmgmt.msc then. However, if that makes your computer boot into the Windows 8.1 on D:, it would be a hard time for you then.

Comment: @bfrguci. When I want activate system reserved I have: only mark a partition as active if it contains a functioning orating system. -- but there isn't any operating system in this partition. Should I proceed?

Comment: Can I use third party applications to do this job?

Comment: You need to make sure that once it doesn't boot after you switch activated partition, you have something that can revert the action. A Windows installation media should do the job. Ubuntu installation media can do the job too... However, may I know, how familiar are you with partitioning/system installation, etc.?

Comment: If you are not very familiar with partitioning/system installation, messing with partitions may very likely cause boot failures, even without really losing important data. In your case, if I were you, I may just use Windows PE to delete D:, and rebuild Windows Boot Manager on the Reserved Partition. However if you are not confident with these or don't even know how to achieve that, maybe a simpler solution for you is to delete files on D: and leave system files alone.

Comment: But please be aware that moving the starting point of a system partition can cause the Windows on it to fail to boot.

Comment: BTW, don't know why this question worth a downvote... The problem itself does take effort to solve. The OP just didn't know exactly the cause of the issue - which is not straight forward in Windows actually...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38460/discussion-between-user2991243-and-bfrguci).

Comment: I activated reserved partition. After restating, my  computer started windows 8.1 (second windows). I added again windows 10 to boot. Now I'm in windows 10 (dual boot) and removed drive D:. What should I do for addin drive D: space to C: now?

Comment: Windows' built in partition manager cannot move a partition. I usually use AOMEI. But I have already warned you that moving a system partition can lead to booting failure, so try at your own risk...